# Join Hashtag list python give a single letter

Tags: python, regex, twitter, hashtag

Hi guys I have a problem. I did a twitter scraper work for my thesis inorder to obtain some texts and hashtags to process. So the problem is the seguent: in the hashtag column, I have all rows such as:

```
['covid19', 'croazia', 'slovenia']
```

Now in order to cluster this text data, I wanto to join all rows into one, in order to have something like this:

```
covid19 croazia slovenia
```

So because of these hashtags are in a pandas column called "Hashtag", to do what I want I used this line of code:

```
df["Hashtag_united"] = df["Hashtag"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
```

But in this way I hadn't the rows as I expected as I wrote, but I had:

```
[ ' c o v i d 1 9 ' , ' c r o a z i a ' , ' s l o v e n i a ' ]
```

What I have to do in order to obtain what I want? Thank you for the time spent for me.
I apologize for the stupid question. Have a good day!

Comment: if you just wanted to get all the distinct hashtags in a string, you can do the following, `df["Hashtag_united"].unique()` loop over this and append to a string

Comment: It looks like each item in the column `Hashtag` is _not_ a list, but a string `"['covid19', 'croazia', 'slovenia']"`. Try `lambda x: " ".join(eval(x))` instead, although `eval` is often avoided.

Comment: @whitespace thank you. I want each row as a single string without [ ] ' ' and with each word as covid19, not with a space between each letter as c o v i d 1 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `"['covid19', 'croazia', 'slovenia']"` in your Hashtag column, you can use:

```py
import ast
df["Hashtag_united"] = df["Hashtag"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

The `ast.literal_eval(x)` will cast the stringified string list into a string list, and `" ".join(...)` will make a string out of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the correct answer was that of @j1-lee. Thank you to all and for all support. You're all great!

Comment: @Jhonny You do not need to use `eval`. Use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: thank you guy. I will vote your answer because also it works and because you always help me a lot. What is the different between the two methods that seem to do the same thing? Thank you

Comment: @Jhonny See [this reference](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-differentiate-eval()-and-ast.literal_eval()-in-python): "*Both `eval()` and `ast.literal_eval()` evaluate strings containing Python code in the current Python environment, but `ast.literal_eval()` restricts its evaluation to a subset of valid Python datatypes, while `eval()` does not.*" So, `ast.literal_eval` is safer. Also, see [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/3832970) SO thread.